# I need basic regex code

Tags: regex, vb.net

```
/edit?o=U&amp;video_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx&amp;show_mt=1
/edit?o=U&amp;show_mt=1&amp;video_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I want get **video_id** query using regex (xxxxxxxxx)
I am using VB.NET

Thanks for help!

M. Deger

Edit: I want only regex code eg: **[^?]+(?:\?video_id=([^&]+).*)?**

Comment: 1) what platform / language are you using? 2) please show what you have tried so far

Comment: Use an HTML and querystring parser, in that order.

Comment: Sorry i edit my question.

Comment: What do you want to match in those strings?

Comment: I want get only video_id= querystring

Comment: This part `\?video_id` of your regex requires a question mark before video_id. Is that what your intent is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested:

`(?<=video_id\s*=\s*)[^&]*(?=&|$)`

or, result in capture group 1

`video_id\s*=\s*([^&]*)(?:&|$)`

Comment: great work. Thank you for help.

Comment: No problem, hopefully it does some of what you need.